# How to store both IPv4 or IPv6 in single column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ipv6, ipv4, inetaddress

Should I use `binary(16)` or `varbinary(16)`?

I know I can use  `getAddress()` in `java.net.InetAddress` (Java) or `System.Net.IPAddress` (C#) to get a `byte[]` representation of both `IPv4` and `IPv6`, but if I need to insert `IPv4` i.e. `binary(4)` into a `binary(16)` field in `SQL Server`, do I need to worry about padding or anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IF you store a `binary(4)` in a `binary(16)` column you'll get back, when you read it, a padded value of length 16. If you want to have dynamic length you must use a `varbinary(16)`. This type retains the length of the data inserted, at the cost of adding extra 2 bytes on-disk (the actual length).

Comment: Since I expect majority of the IP will still be in IPv4, I guess varbinary(16) makes sense.

Comment: And the cost of creating a variable length field

Comment: For the exact cost details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085.aspx and/or http://sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx

Comment: Remus Rusanu, would u use binary(16) or varbinary(16)?

Answer (score 8):

Use [v4-in-v6 address embedding](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6IPv4AddressEmbedding.htm) to convert your ipv4 addresses to ipv6 format; then you can treat them all identically.

Comment: wouldn't it be just like binary(4) with 12x zero byte padding in front?

Comment: Presumably you expect some of the entries in this database column to be actual ipv6 addresses.  The point of v4-in-v6 embedding is that more of your application code won't have to care about the difference (it can just pretend it has nothing but v6 addresses).